# Way to record changes to an object using F#

Tags: f#

Is there a clever way to record changes made to an object in F#?

I have been researching F# as a way to build an object model that replicates itself over the network. One task I need to solve is how to detect changes made to objects so I can send only changes to clients

Note: I am looking for answers *other* than "implement INotifyPropertyChanged" or "do something that can easily be done in C#". If that is the only way to solve the problem in F# then F# is not the tool im looking for.

Why F#? Because I am not satisfied with the ways this state observer pattern is implemented in C#. Hence I am investigating if there is some elegant way to implement it in a dynamic language, starting with F#.

Comment: Just curious: why do you insist on a *language* -specific solution, when you have platform-specific solutions available? (INotifyPropertyChanged, proxies)

Comment: Because implementing a INPC solution in C# is a complete PITA (the options are code generation, proxies, AOP none of which I would describe as nice). I am currently investigating whether dynamic languages can provide a nicer solution - F# being the one im currently investigating because it ships with VS2010 and so would have the lowest barrier to entry should it happen to be able to elegantly implement observable objects. I don't mind using a specific language to define my observable types if it gives me a low maintenance, elegant, interoperable solution.

Comment: F#'s not a dynamic language - it's concise, but it's statically typed.  If you're looking for a language supporting this type of metaprogramming, F# may not be your best bet.

Comment: I agree with kvb's comment. You can only implement this the way you want on a dynamic language.

Comment: Ah ok. For some reason I was under the impression F# was dynamic. Then perhaps I will re-ask this question for dynamic languages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of detecting and notifying changes as they happen, you could make your classes immutable (for example by using the standard immutable types like records and unions, or by making the object contain only immutable things). Then you could write a function that "diffs" two instances of a class, and have some agent that looks for changes on a schedule or based on some trigger and sends the diffs to the other end.

Because the data would be immutable, the agent would only need to retain a pointer to the version it last sent. The diffing function itself could either be written by hand for each class, which would allow for an efficient implementation that takes the properties of the data into account, or you could write a generic one using reflection.

Comment: I thought of exactly this idea. Was not sure if it was viable. Its worth trying, but if anyone has tried something like this let me know

Comment: I am accepting this answer as its the only one that answers the intention of my question: how to actually record changes (not how to implement INPC)

Answer (score 4):

An example of `INotifyPropertyChanged` use in F#.

```
type DemoCustomer() =
    let mutable someValue = 0
    let propertyChanged = Event<_, _>()

    member this.MyProperty
        with get() = someValue
        and  set(x) =
            someValue <- x
            propertyChanged.Trigger(this, PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"))

    interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? and raise events that cause the data to be replicated when it is changed?

Comment: I was hoping there was some clever way thats peculiar to F#. Perhaps something like decorators in Python. Or a way to snoop on bindings as their dependants change. Stuff like that. Something elegant that cant be done in C#. From what I can see using INPC and events in F# is even uglier than C# so there is no desire to go down that route.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726364/how-to-control-method-behavior-via-an-attribute

Comment: In F# you can just make an anonymous class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233237.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a proxy library: [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html), [LinFu](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LinFuPart1.aspx), [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html), etc.

Using a proxy library you can easily [implement INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/04/implement-inotifypropertychanged-with-castledynamicproxy/) in a transparent, non-invasive way.

Comment: The problem with INPC is its not a good interface for all purposes. One general complaint is the magic string property name. The second major problem for "recording state changes" is that the new value is not captured at the time the event fires, meaning the observer has to go back and retrieve the value - this has implications for performance and threading.

Comment: @Schneider: no magic strings visible in a proxy solution. Exposing the new value in a proxy is also trivial to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use reflection to walk the object fields and see what changed? If they contain immutable F# data then equality checks will pick up the changes. You can then send the diffs relative to the last sent object.

Comment: the problem with this is *when* would you walk the fields.